# codeigniter multiple spaces into single space

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I am new to codeigniter, I just want to know if there is any way to convert multiple spaces into one space only

here is my code in controller/validation part

```
    public function main_page_add_enc(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]|regex_match[/^[A-Za-z ]+$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
$data['view']=$this->Student_model->stud_view();
        $this->load->view('main_page',$data);
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('index');
        }
    }
```

if i put:
ss    ssssss

it will become:
ss ssssss

Comment: If there are more than one space between two or more words then your want to make it one space. is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

> First wiith codeigniter string helper

```
    $this->load->helper('string');


    $string = reduce_multiples($string," ");//this will be double spaces
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html

> Second You can use this

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
 $output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html